# Pause wavesurfer when scrolled out of viewport

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I'm trying to add multiple instances of wavesurfer.js on my page. I have my HTML structure like this:

```
<div class = "audio-player" src = "/aud1.mp3"></div>
<div class = "audio-player" src = "/aud2.mp3"></div>
```

and my script is like this (loaded in `<head>` wih `defer` attribute after the `wavesurfer.js` script`):

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var mediaA = document.querySelectorAll('.audio-player')
  if (mediaA != null) {
    mediaA.forEach(medium => {
      var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
        /* wavesurfer config */
      })
      wavesurfer.load(medium.getAttribute('src'))
      window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        if (outOfViewport(medium) {
          wavesurfer.pause()
        }
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to pause the wavesurfer instance once it's scrolled out of viewport.

As you can see from my code, I'm adding multiple scroll event listeners to the window and I would like to avoid that. I would like to group all my scroll events into one and make it a single function. However, I don't know how I can access the already created wavesurfer instance.

I'm looking for something like:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  /* my other scroll stuff */
  var mediaA = document.querySelectorAll('.audio-player')
  if (mediaA != null) {
    mediaA.forEach(medium => {
      if (outOfViewport(medium) {
        medium.paue()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

except, the `medium.pause()` should actually be called on the wavesurfer instance and not the HTML element (like it's doing in the code I posted).

Is what I am planning to do going to be an improvement in terms of performance than I've already done? Are multiple scroll event listeners going to be a problem than one scroll event listener managing multiple elements? If yes, then how exactly do I implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to store the instances in an array:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var wavesurfers = []
  var mediaA = document.querySelectorAll('.audio-player')
  if (mediaA != null) {
    mediaA.forEach(medium => {
      var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
        /* wavesurfer config */
      })
      wavesurfers.push(wavesurfer)
      wavesurfer.load(medium.getAttribute('src'))
    })
  }

  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    /* my other scroll stuff */
    if (wavesurfers != []) {
      wavesurfers.forEach(wavesurfer => {
        if (outOfViewport(wavesurfer.mediaContainer.parentElement)) {
          wavesurfer.pause()
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```